# Why are my buttons going out of screen in my Ionic app?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2, bootstrap-4

I have created a simple chat form in Ionic.

**Problem:** Buttons are going out of screen.

It looks like this this -

[image]

My `chat.html`

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>communicationgiven</ion-title>
    <button ion-button (click)="close()" style="margin-left: 90%;margin-top: -3%">Close</button>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

  <ion-list>
  <div>

  <p *ngFor="let list of list; let i = index;">
    <ion-item>
        <!-- <p style="color: #1bb0f4;font-size: 20px;">Tagto {{list.TAG_TO}}</p> -->
        <p style="color: #1bb0f4;"> {{list.TAG_FROM}}</p>
        <p style="color: #d2dce1;"> {{list.TAG}}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </p>
  </div>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>


<ion-footer class="footer">
  <form #com="ngForm" (submit)="onsubmit(com.value)">
    <ion-input placeholder="TAG" type="text" name="TAG" ngModel ></ion-input>
    <button ion-button type="submit" style="margin-left: 90%;margin-top: -5%;">Submit</button>
  </form>

</ion-footer>
```

I want to know why my buttons are going out of the page; how can I make sure they stay inside the screen, irrespective of the screen size?

What is the best practice here? I am fairly new in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use below code for left button

```
<ion-header>

    <ion-navbar>
        <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>

        <ion-title>
            Page Title
        </ion-title>

        <ion-buttons end>
            <button ion-button icon-only (click)="openModal()">
                <ion-icon name="options"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

For footer you can use ion-grid

```
<ion-footer class="footer">
  <form #com="ngForm" (submit)="onsubmit(com.value)">
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-9>
                <ion-input placeholder="TAG" type="text" name="TAG" ngModel ></ion-input>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-3>
                <button ion-button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </form>
</ion-footer>
```

For more info please refer this

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Navbar/

Comment: what about the bottom button ?

Answer (score 0):

you had given  style="margin-left: 90% that is margin from left side is 90% so obviously it will go out of screen, try to decrease the value.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this one as I can't replicate the issue locally with what you've provided.

I'd start by reducing the `margin-left: 90%` on the button element, see how that goes.

In regard to best practices, an important one is to not use inline styles. That is putting styles in the `style` html attribute. Instead try using an external style sheet or at least an internal style sheet, see: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: how about my bottom button ?

Comment: @user2828442 I’m not sure what you mean by that. Maybe also change the margin-left for the bottom button?